# knitr changes (1) to <ol> when rendering html?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

The following content of a .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{r cars}
mtcars$am <- sprintf("(%s)", as.character(mtcars$am))
knitr::kable(mtcars, format = "html")
```
````

Will show ordered lists `<ol><li></li></ol>` in the `am` column, instead of the numbers in brackets (as produced with the `sprintf`) after rendering to html.

Is this intended? How can I work around this and have numbers in brackets show as they are in the html output?

The output of `knitr::kable` seems to be fine, showing:

`<td style="text-align:left;"> (1) </td>`

Details:

- Using knitr 1.20
- RStudio Server 1.1.453
- note that removing `format = "html"` does not resolve the issue as in the real-life context I would like to do advanced formatting with css e.g. based on the classes of the produced tables

A **quick workaround solution** based on Michael Harper's accepted answer may be a method like so:

```
replacechars <- function(x) UseMethod("replacechars")
replacechars.default <- function(x) x
replacechars.character <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("(", "&lpar;", x, fixed = TRUE)
  x <- gsub(")", "&rpar;", x, fixed = TRUE)
  x
}
replacechars.factor <- function(x) {
  levels(x) <- replacechars(levels(x))
  x
}
replacechars.data.frame <- function(x) {
  dfnames <- names(x)
  x <- data.frame(lapply(x, replacechars), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(x) <- dfnames
  x
}
```

Example use:

```
mtcars <- datasets::mtcars

# Create a character with issues
mtcars$am <- sprintf("(%s)", as.character(mtcars$am))

# Create a factor with issues
mtcars$hp <- as.factor(mtcars$hp)
levels(mtcars$hp) <- sprintf("(%s)", levels(mtcars$hp))

replacechars(mtcars)
```

Comment: @zack this is true, `knitr::kable` will then automatically select the format to produce - in this case it will create a markdown table, which gets rendered as expected. This however does not resolve my issue, as I need the html format (to be able to format the output further with css, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the `format="html"` argument, you could try using the HTML character entities for the parentheses (`&lpar` and `&rpar`) and then add the argument `escape = FALSE`:

````
```{r cars}
mtcars$am <- sprintf("&lpar;%s&rpar;", as.character(mtcars$am))
knitr::kable(mtcars, format = "html", escape = FALSE)
```
````

[image]

Still not entirely sure of what is causing the error though. It seems that the specific combination of parentheses is being processed strangely by **knitr**.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue, accepting your answer. I also raised and issue on knitr's github - https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1641.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to escape the parentheses, e.g.,

```r
mtcars$am <- sprintf("\\(%s)", as.character(mtcars$am))
```

Then you won't need `escape = FALSE`.

See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#backslash-escapes in Pandoc's Manual.